# Django celery tasks working very long

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, supervisord

I use celery, supervisor and flower

supervisor conf:

`command=/web/venv/bin/python manage.py celeryd -E -l info -c 2 --maxtasksperchild=1 -Ofair`

```
directory=/web/
stdout_logfile=/web/log/
redirect_stderr=true
user=web
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
```

Problem when start from python shell, task works very fast. If from celery, works very very long. I don't know what the problem. Maybe someone can help ?

Comment: after taking too much time will that execute of get timed out?

Comment: which command are you using to run from shell?

Comment: @ArunG, yes get time out

Comment: @AjayGupta like:
`
from project.tasks import test_task
   test_task()
`

Comment: something related to venv (virtualenv) i think, path maybe!!

Comment: @ArunG task works, but very long, but sometimes fail with timeout

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the same by adding celery from admin, that might solution

```
http://www.yourhost.com/admin/djcelery/
```

Comment: and how this help? 
celery works but some tasks works very long, when I run tasks manually from shell  for testing, they are works fast

Comment: Ideally code should behave in same way in your case unless its env issue. check with that. rather than initiating code from shell, create a api url call and put a pdb and work around

Comment: ok i will try, but i run task from shell, same way like celery doing